# How to build an APK for my Ionic Angular project?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working on an Ionic Angular project and I need to build an APK file to distribute my app to Android devices. I have tried researching and following various tutorials, but I'm still facing some difficulties. Could someone please guide me through the process of building an APK for my Ionic Angular project?

**ionic capacitor add android**

ionic : File C:\Users\team\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For
more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- ionic capacitor add android
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Comment: do you want to push to the store or just want an apk on your local machine to be able to send it manually?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set _Execution_Policies

Just Open powershell in administrative mode and run the following command

"Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"

Then

1. add android (npx cap add android)
2. build .www folder (ionic build)
3. sync you project (npx cap sync android)
4. open android studio ( npx cap open android )

In android Studio go to build and click (APK)

Hope this will work